# AWS: Convert String to Region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I do not want to hardcode region id and pass region name as String from command line. Is there a way to do that?
Hardcoding:

```
Region s3Region = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1); 
Non Hardcoded but not working:
Region s3Region = Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(awsRegion));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answering the question that I think you mean to ask:

If you have an Amazon region name like, for example, "us-east-1" then you can easily convert it to a RegionEndpoint:

```
RegionEndpoint endpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Regions.valueOf(awsRegion)` should help.
Full code:

```java
Region s3Region = Region.getRegion(Regions.valueOf(awsRegion.toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: Should it be toUpperCase() or toLowerCase()?  It says the string should match the constants specified in the Regions class, which is all lower case.

Answer (score 1):

For ***software.amazon.awssdk*** use the below code.

```
 import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;

    Region region= Region.of("Your-Region");
```

Note: Not for **com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk**